# Mediaelements applying into widget like a post?

Tags: html, wordpress, mediaelement.js

Mediaelements search html5 media tags **video** and **audio**   and replace it by yourself player. It works on wordpress posts fine.

But at widget i would like to add audio streaming link and i didnt want use any third party player. I want to use mediaelements from wordpress core.

How  can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Black Studio TinyMCE Widget adds the tinymce to widgets. I think it also works fine with mediaelements.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/black-studio-tinymce-widget/